# Какое это предложение и нужна ли там запятая?

Tags: запятые, грамматика, синтаксический-разбор

***Всегда найдется (,) за что похвалить.***

Запятая здесь факультативна или нет?

И как сделать грамматический разбор предложения в обоих случаях, чтобы обосновать решение?

Спасибо.

Примечание. Философия такая: нужно поддерживать своих друзей и родных, даже если для этого нет особых оснований.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна по следующему правилу Розенталя:
Внутри выражений типа *есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, **найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что сказать**, осталось на что жить*, состоящих из глагола *быть*, или ***найти (найтись)***, или *остаться* и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (*кто, **что**, где, куда, когда* и т.д.) и неопределенной формы другого глагола, запятая не ставится:
*Нашли чем удивить.

Не нашёлся что сказать.

Нашла где модничать.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146
Примеры из оригинального справочника Розенталя:
*Найдется с кем посоветоваться.

Он не нашелся что ответить и промолчал.

Нашел с кем бороться!

Нашли чем хвалиться.

Мы найдем чем оправдать свое отсутствие.

Он стал искать обо что вытереть руки.

Я не нашелся что возразить ему и ушел.*

Предлог не нарушает цельность, а выступает связкой, сглаживая переход.

Для потери фразеологической цельности обычно необходимо несколько слов:
*Я мог петь, сколько мне тогда было угодно* (пример Розенталя). || Три слова **внутри** цельного сочетания. А у нас одно и не внутри, а перед.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Меня смущает объем предложения и постановка ударения. (Сравнить: Всегда есть за что похвалить.)  Вы куда ставите ударение? Мне кажется, что следует выделить "всегда" или "найдется", а тогда там нужна пауза.

Comment: В примере Розенталя про вытирание рук похожая ситуация. Слово "всегда" способствует ударению, но можно и правильнее без него и без паузы. Для запятой надо добавить слово "можно", тогда уже от ударения не уйти.

Comment: Если бы предложение имело продолжение, то ударение на "похвалить" было бы оправданным, а сейчас оно мне кажется странным, как будто требуется продолжение текста. А вам как кажется?

Comment: Маленькое ударение на "найдётся" мне кажется нормальным, а вот полноценное с паузой — плохо звучит, там ощущается цельность. "Найдётся" по смыслу можно заменить на "будет", там нет полноценного значения слова "найтись", что указывает на цельность. Мне ударение на "похвалить" странным не кажется.

Comment: Ну ладно, есть у меня некоторые сомнения, но на вашей стороне книга –  там запятой не. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Где-то месяц назад был вопрос с таким же по синтаксису предложением, как и ваше: ‟Я не знаю чем объяснить запятую”. Я считаю, что такие предложения являются простыми, потому что в таких предложениях ‟чем” обозначает что-то, в отличии от случаев, когда ‟чем” является союзным словом и просто выполняет функцию связи предложений; потому что часть после ‟чем” не является предложением (чем — дополнение, объяснить — несогласованное определение); потому что если считать такие предложения составными, то нам придется быть последовательными и считать составными такие предложения: ‟Я знаю способ объяснить запятую”.
Но в нац. корпусе при сочетаниях ‟я знаю чем” в подавляющем большинстве случаев стоит запятая. Считаю это массовой ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнеие. Если мы распространим предложение, то  запятую придется поставить, например: Всегда найдется (то), за что человека можно похвалить.  Здесь ЗА ЧТО - союзное слово в СПП. Но если предложение короткое, его можно приравнять к дополнению, например: Всегда найдется повод для похвалы. В некоторых  (пограничных) случаях приходится делать выбор, как, например, здесь.

Comment: В вашем предложении запятая нужна, потому что слово ‟можно” (безличный глагол) делает предложение односоставным, придаточным.

Comment: *Считаю это массовой ошибкой* — не надо путать реально существующие нормы и то, как, на ваш взгляд, было бы лучше. В языке нет последовательности во всём.

Comment: Нигде не написано, что в таких ситуациях нужно ставить запятую; запятая в таких ситуациях противоречит синтаксису; в авторитетном справочнике написано то, что запятую в таких ситуациях ставить не следует — ваш ответ со ссылкой на Розенталя.

Comment: У Розенталя речь лишь о *есть, найти(сь), остаться*. В другом справочнике сказано, что такое может быть и с некоторыми другими глаголами (Розенталь других не обнаружил, просто допускает их существование). Эти глаголы — исключения. Прочитайте пункт 2. 2) здесь (про неполные предложения): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136